# JavaScript: Continue with function after another function call finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing

#### Edits: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/wQZdM/

The fiddle should be used to help illustrate what I'm trying to do and what's happening.  The sub-selects should be populated with the second option value.

---

#### Original Question:

Not sure the best way to ask.  I'm creating a testing script to autofill inputs on a form.

It includes a series of drop-down `select` boxes, which populate other `select` options in an onChange event.  When trying to auto-populate the form, the sub-selects don't have any options.

```
console.clear();

// non-select inputs
$(':input:not([type="hidden"],[type="button"])').each(function(){
   $(this).val($(this).attr('name'))          // test value is simple input's name
});

// select inputs
var count=0, cutoff=7500;
$('select').each(function(){
   var t = $(this);
   var c = t.children('option');

   while( c.length <= 1 && count < cutoff){
      count++;
      c = $(this).children('option');       // tried not using the cache'd variable
      if (!(count % 10))
         console.log(count, c.length, "No Options");  // debugging -- never exists early

      setTimeout(function(){},0);           // not really doing anything
   }

   t.val( c.eq(1).val() );                  // set value to second option value
   t.trigger('change');                     // calls the onChange even if it doesnt exist
});

// verify it does have data
console.log($('#sub-select').children('option').length); // does have options
```

There's an AJAX call in the change event.  I could modify the callback, but this is just a simple set script for testing, that is run from console.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your first selector is rather much. It can be simplified to: `input:not([type="hidden"],:button)`.

Comment: The problem is not very clear from the code and explanation.

Comment: You should include pure Javascript or add a jQuery tag. About 80% of Javascript developers will not deal with jQuery questions.
But keep in mind, about 90% of statistics on internet comments are made up on the fly.

Comment: Well, one way of asking would be to actually ask a question... It's hard to tell what problem you might have, as most of the code seems to have no real purpose at all.

Comment: @pimvdb: that includes the button, which I don't want.  I did have a typo (should have been submit instead of button twice).

Comment: @Guffa: thank you for looking at this, I appreciate everyone's help.  I'm not sure how to make this cleaner, other than to further elaborate what's changing.  I'll try to make an example when I have time in JSFiddle, I was hoping the experience of the community would be able to interpret what is happening in the code (looping through inputs and just setting the value).

Comment: @Mario: I agree, there's jQuery involved, which makes it jquery-related, but the heart of the problem may be just pure Javascript.  I'm not sure, since it's the jQuery object that isn't being populated.

Comment: Not really sure what you want to do. But maybe deferred objects can help: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: I'm closing this question and opening a [new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262986/jquery-javascript-autopopulate-dynamically-populated-elements), since I've edited the question so much.  Hopefully, I'll avoid some of the confusion, thanks to all of your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what your code is trying to do

But answering the question How to continue with function after another function call finishes :-

assuming you have a list of functions which are all asynchronous you can nest them to continue

to the next asynchronous function ...
    asyncCall(callback1) {
      callback1(callback2) {
        callback2(...)
      }
    }

Checkout https://github.com/caolan/async for some elegant ways to do this

this example calls all functions in order even though they are asynchronous.

```
async.series([
        function(callback){
            setTimeout(function(){
                call_order.push(1);
                callback(null, 1);
            }, 25);
        },
        function(callback){
            setTimeout(function(){
                call_order.push(2);
                callback(null, 2);
            }, 50);
        },
        function(callback){
            setTimeout(function(){
                call_order.push(3);
                callback(null, 3,3);
            }, 15);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Use Synchronous AJAX request http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
var html = $.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  async: false
 }).responseText;
```

2) Instead of using the .each use .eq(index) and just call it in order.

```
function FakeEach(idx) {
    if(idx >= 7500) return;
    var $obj = $('select').eq(idx);
    if($obj.length == 0) return;
    ...
    $obj.trigger('change');
    window.setTimeout(function() { FakeEach(idx++); }, 0);
}
```

Comment: The problem could be how `each()` orders items.  If it's in DOM order, though, that shouldn't be the problem.  sub-select's options are based on select's value.  So, looking at the loop the value is changed on the select, then the change event is called (calls AJAX, populates the sub-select), the next item in each() should be the sub-select, which I want to wait until it is populated (has `option`s).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are starting an AJAX request in the function, and expect that the response arrives before the function ends. As long as you are using an asynchronous request, this will never happen. You have to exit your function before the code that handles the response can run. Javascript is single threaded, so as long as your function is running, no other code can run.

The solution to the problem is to put the code that uses the data in the success callback function that is called after the response has arrived. Eventhough you usually write that function inside the function that makes the AJAX call, it's a separate function that will run later.

If you really need the data in the same function as the AJAX call, you would need to make a synchronous request. This is a killer for the user experience, though, as the entire browser freezes while it is waiting for the response.

Comment: Yes I realize that about the synchronicity of the AJAX bit, but I don't really want to muck with the production code, since I'm only trying to create a test, to auto populate dynamically populated elements.  I have to believe there's another way, which may be to extend the onchange function.  I thought you could do a setTimeout and let other operations proceed, which is why I put that in a `while` loop originally -- I don't think this worked too well.  When debugging, I do see that the AJAX does return while the `while` loop is processing.

Comment: @vol7ron: Even if the response arrives while your loop is running, the code that handles the response can't run. You can simulate the asynchronous part of an AJAX call using a timeout. The timeout callback represents the success callback of the AJAX call: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/kdFFf/

Comment: thanks for your help, I've created a new question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262986/jquery-javascript-autopopulate-dynamically-populated-elements , since my original question may have deterred/confused people. I've voted to close this question.