# jQuery/Javascript: Autopopulate Dynamically Populated Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, testing

#### Problem

---

> I am trying to auto-populate dynamically populated elements (eg `select` inputs).  The problem is caused due to the asynchronicity of AJAX, so I need some sort of "wait until thread is complete".
>
> I've attempted implementing a `while` loop with a setTimeout(0), but that did not go as expected.

#### Demo

---

> #### http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/wQZdM/

#### Conditions

---

> 1. I ***cannot*** edit the source code, since this is supposed to be a tool to auto-populate forms for testing.

Comment: I don't understand -- how can you fix this if you can't edit the source code?

Comment: I'm voting to close the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260997/javascript-continue-with-function-after-another-function-call-finishes) I started, since it may have confused some people.

Comment: @vol7ron: This one confuses me more. Voting to close this as a duplicate

Comment: I guess he means this is a third party tool, so he can't have access to the other code running.

Comment: **This is not a duplicate btw.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to handle this. Observe all the select elements for future changes.

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQZdM/8/).

Basically here's how I changed it:

```
var observer  = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        handleSelect(mutation.target);
    });
});
$('select').each(function () {
    observer.observe(this, { childList : true }); // We observe the elementw
    handleSelect(this);
});

function handleSelect(el) {
    var t = $(el);
    var c = t.children('option');

    t.val(c.eq(1).val()); // set value to second option value
    t.trigger('change'); // calls the onChange even if it doesnt exist
}
```

Note that `MutationObserver` is available only in modern browsers. You can use either of the follwoing shims/pollyfills(they each have different browser support, so choose the one you need):

- https://github.com/megawac/MutationObserver.js
- https://github.com/Polymer/MutationObservers

But this might be kind of sneaky in testing tools. Generally with my experience from selenium or casperjs, I just would wait for the new options to arrive then select that option.

Comment: I didn't see that, I can't even remember the purpose of the question.  I think I was debugging a form input via Firebug and wanted some way to quickly populate generic form values.  At least, I think that's why I mentioned that the source code could not be touched.  Regardless, I didn't see your polyfill links and have retracted my comments above.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery `ajax` function takes a `success` callback function. You can use that to auto populate after the ajax call has successfully completed. Are you saying your cannot modify the ajax code?

Answer (score -1):

Add it to your

```
success : function(){}
```

callback function. But if you really can't edit your code, you can't fix it ...

Comment: The tool will be for page testing forms.  So, source code shouldn't be edited, on the other hand, the testing code can, so maybe I can override some functions.